# How to Resize a Canvas in UWP

Tags: c#, canvas, uwp, resize, runtime

I have a view that extends Canvas.
Such view is positioned inside another Canvas.

```
public class MyView : Canvas
{
  //this is my view
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  PointerEventManager manager = new PointerEventManager(); // utility to manage the resizing event...
  MyView myView = new MyView();
  myView.PointerPressed += manager.OnPointerDown; 
  myView.PointerMoved += manager.OnPointerMoved;
  myView.PointerReleased += manager.OnPointerUp;
  Canvas parent = new Canvas();
  parent.Children.Add(myView);
  // other stuff...
}
```

I want the user to be able to resize myView.

Note that such view should also be draggable by the user, and this is the main reason I want such view to be a Canvas.

The code for the method `manager.OnPointerMoved` looks like this:

```
protected void OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myView.Width = myView.Width + 15; // enlarge by 15 pixel the width 
    myView.Height = myView.Height + 50; // enlarge by 50 pixel the height
}
```

To change the Width and Height of myView is not working.

What can I do to properly resize myView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of who will bump into this question in the future, I managed it using a `RelativePanel` rather than a Canvas.
With that I can move&drag changing Margin property, and resizing using Width&Height properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `GridSplitter` provided in [Microsoft community toolkit sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/gridsplitter).
I placed a canvas inside a Grid. The size of canvas can be modified by grid splitter and Yes the canvas is draggable. [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/5.0.0/)

[image]

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    x:Name="YourPage"

    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid"  
        Margin="48"
        BorderThickness="0,0,1,1"
        BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightChromeHighBrush}"
        Height="500"
        VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Canvas Background="Red" CanDrag="True" ></Canvas>

        <!--Column Grid Splitter-->
        <controls:GridSplitter
            GripperCursor="Default"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Grid.Column="0"
            ResizeDirection="Auto"
            ResizeBehavior="BasedOnAlignment"
            CursorBehavior="ChangeOnSplitterHover"
            Width="16">
            <controls:GridSplitter.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="-8" />
            </controls:GridSplitter.RenderTransform>

        </controls:GridSplitter>

        <!--Row Grid Splitter-->
        <controls:GridSplitter
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Height="16">
            <controls:GridSplitter.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform Y="-8" />
            </controls:GridSplitter.RenderTransform>
            <controls:GridSplitter.Element>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         IsHitTestVisible="False"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Text="&#xE76F;"
                         Foreground="White"
                         FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets">
                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </controls:GridSplitter.Element>
        </controls:GridSplitter>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score -1):

I see several problems with your code.

**Firstly**, you didn't set the `Background` of `MyView` (you didn't mention). So, it's null, thus, it won't catch any `PointerEvent`. So, that's there.

**Secondly**, if you pass the first problem, yet,  you didn't set the `Width` and `Height` of `MyView`. If that's the case, both of them are `NaN`, which will prevent any of these two line from working:

```
myView.Width = myView.Width + 15; // what's NaN + 15 ? 
myView.Height = myView.Height + 50; // huh ?
```

**And at last**, regarding

> Note that such view should also be draggable by the user, and this is
>   the main reason I want such view to be a Canvas.

Well, you can utilize the `Margin` property of any `FrameworkElement` to specify it's position in it's parent's layout.